# multi-line diary event?

Tags: diary

I'd like to have diary entries/events with multiple lines. The usual diary format interprets newlines as delimiting events:

```
Monday
  event A every monday
  event B every monday
  event C every monday
```

Something like `diary-list-entries` gives you three entries. I want to have, say, multiple lines for event A:

```
Monday
  event A every monday
    some more stuff about event A
    yet more stuff about event A
  event B every monday
  event C every monday
```

...and to have `diary-list-entries` or similar make the event A string have newlines in it.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve making up my own format and writing lisp to handle that?

(The motivation here is to have org mode entries with a properties block, but this isn't strictly org-mode-specific.)

Comment: So I create a diary file like this (where `\n` is actually a newline): `04/19/2021  Event A\n      foo\n      bar\n      baz\n04/19/2021 Event B\n04/19/2021 Event C\n`, I go to the calendar and press `d`. I get everything. So I'm not sure what you are seeing (or not seeing). Can you be more explicit about what you do? In particular, what does "The usual diary format interprets newlines as delimiting events" really mean?

Comment: *facepalm* It never occurred to me that the date specifiers -- `4/19/2021`, or `* 1` or whatever -- could be repeated, and that each instance represents a single event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @NickD, I see that I should just repeat the date specification. For some reason that didn't occur to me. So in my example, I should just do:

```
Monday
 event A every monday
 some more stuff about event A
 yet more stuff about event A
Monday
 event B every monday
 further lines about this event / diary entry for event B
Monday
  event C every monday
```